# How to prevent a loop in a bi-directional relationship

Tags: java, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship, entities, bidirectional

Say we have the following two entities.

**Library**

```
public class Library
{
    private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public boolean add(Book book)
    {
        return books.add(book);
    }
    public boolean remove(Book book)
    {
        return books.remove(book);
    }
}
```

**Book**

```
public class Book
{
    private Library library;
    public setLibrary(Library library)
    {
        this.library = library;
    }
}
```

This is a bi-directional relationship which will most likely break pretty quick. Even though you add a book to a library, the library of the book is not updated. And even though you update the library of a book, the library isn't updated.

So, how would you maintain this bi-directional relationship in a good way? I could of course just do an `add`+`remove` in the `setLibrary` and vice versa, but this would as far as I can see cause a loop which would probably end in a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a "owner" for the relation. Does the library "own" the book or does the book own the library?

The answer to that question tells you who updates the "slave" entity.

I feel that the library owns the book, so the "add book to library" code should go into the library which will then update the back references.

Comment: Ok, so this is how it would generally be done then? So in this case the `Book` could be dumb and you'd only call `setLibrary` in the `Library` class?

Comment: @Svish: Yes that is the idea, you can only add books to the library which then sets the library of the book. You cannot directly set the library on a book.

Comment: Yes. It's a workaround because veredesmarald suggestion is too slow on todays computers. If the question "is this book already in the library" would have the complexity O(1) (= needs the same time, no matter how big the library), we could afford to have the add code on both sides.

Comment: Makes sense. Think I'll do it this way then :)

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend Aaron's method of defining a relationship owner, an alternative that allows the `set`/`add`/`remove` methods to remain where they are is to also define corresponding `has` methods (`hasBook` in `Library` and `hasLibrary` in `Book`). Before calling the `add` or `remove` method on the other end of the relation, you first query if it already exists, and if it does don't call it.

Comment: That would be a perfect solution if the check was fast. Todays computers are still too slow for this :-(

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: I agree, which is why I said up front I prefer your approach, but I still felt it was worthwhile to point this out as an option.

Comment: Yeah, think I'll do what @Aaron suggests, but this was a good point too, which I might use in other circumstances :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I being dumb?

```
public boolean add(Book book)
{
   book.setLibrary(this);
   return books.add(book);
}
public boolean remove(Book book)
{
   book.setLibrary(null);
   return books.remove(book);
}
```

Comment: Nope. Problem is if you in addition to this do `this.books.remove(this);this.books = books; this.books.add(this);` in the `setLibrary` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your proposed solution, couldn't you check references for equality to avoid loop?

```
public boolean add(Book book)
{
   if(book.getLibrary != this) book.setLibrary(this);
   return books.add(book);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work: If the book was already in a different library, the library reference in the book wouldn't be updated and you'd end up with a book that is in several libraries (from the lib's point of view) but the book would think it's just in one of them.